# How can I exclude the backup mimetypes.xml file from my MarkLogic backups?

Tags: database, marklogic

How can i stop the backup mimetypes.xml file when taking the backups of marklogic database i dont find any option in the admin console to disable this
[image]

I tried all the option in the admin console i did not found any options regarding this

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the mimetypes.xml from your backup?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. It's part of the cluster configuration, and included in the backup so that you can restore.

Have you made changes to the cluster mimetypes?

I didn't see it included in a backup on a system that had no changes to the mimetypes, but after adding an entry it started adding to the backup.

Comment: can i know how can i check which are new entries added to the mimetypes , i have checked in the admin console i did not find any difference with the other environment which mimetypes.xml files are not present in the backups. how can i cross verify?